# Changing the mask height depending on a responsive image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Having a problem in trying to copy the height of a responsive image to my mask on first load and on every time the window is resized. I've tried a few js scripts, but still I cant make it happen.

It is really a responsive image slider with a div(mask) exactly over it whatever the viewport screen size is.

this is my jQuery script:

```
function maskInit(){
   var offsetDots = $("#slide").offset().top + $("#slide").height() + "px";
   $("#mask").height() = offsetDots;  
}
$(document).ready(function() {
maskInit(); 
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    maskInit();
});
```

and my CSS:

```
#slide{
    height: 10vw; /* to simulate a responsive image */
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: 0;
}
#mask{    
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: gray;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

[I've setup a jsFiddle here to simulate my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ga32py7e/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with your script.

You are **NOT** setting the mask height with this:

```
$("#mask").height() = offsetDots;
```

**Check [jQuery .height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)**

Instead use it this way:

```
$("#mask").height(offsetDots);
```

or you can set via css:

```
$("#mask").css({"height":offsetDots});
```

[Here's your updated jsFIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ga32py7e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`.height()` is a function so you can not do `$("#mask").height() = offsetDots;` use   `$("#mask").height(offsetDots);` or by `.css({"height":offsetDots})` to set height.